# Magento 1.9 : Product details Page error Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addCss()

Tags: magento-1.9

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head::addCss(), 0 passed in /home/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 348 and at least 1 expected in /home/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php:53 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(348): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head->addCss() #1 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(214): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateAction(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) #2 /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#3 /home//public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() #4 /home//public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Produc in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 53
```

Comment: check files this `addCss` function getting blank value.

Comment: Post your css adding code here

Answer (score 1):

You are appealing to a nonexistent element.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error when i was setup a magento 1.9 website locally.
Please go to /app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php on line 53 and change the code as below:

-public function addCss($name, $params = "")

+public function addCss($name="", $params = "")

It works for me. Cheers.